# ACAccountTypeIdentifierLinkedIn not available on IOS

Tags: ios, ios7, linkedin-api

I am trying to create an app on iOS7 that requires the users to authenticate with their LinkedIn Account.

Just tried to map the code I had already for Twitter login for this.

```
ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierLinkedIn];
```

But my Xcode says that ACAccountTypeIdentifierLinkedIn is not available in IOS

I am running IOS 10.9 and the [developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountTypeClassRef/ACAccountType.html) say that ACAccountTypeIdentifierLinkedIn is available for IOS 10.9 and above.

Why is this issue happening. And are there any guides out there on integrating linkedIN with an IOS7 App?

Comment: running Xcode Version 5.0.1

Answer (score 1):

From official docs:

> ACAccountTypeIdentifierLinkedIn
>
> Identifier for the LinkedIn account type.
>
> Available in **OS X** v10.9 and later.
>
> Declared in ACAccountType.h.

**That is, this type is declared for OS X 10.9**

From ACAccountType.h in XCode Version 5.0.1 (5A2053)

Note that the last line:

```
// The identifiers for supported system account types are listed here:
ACCOUNTS_EXTERN NSString * const ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 5_0);
ACCOUNTS_EXTERN NSString * const ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 6_0);
ACCOUNTS_EXTERN NSString * const ACAccountTypeIdentifierSinaWeibo NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 6_0);
ACCOUNTS_EXTERN NSString * const ACAccountTypeIdentifierTencentWeibo NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 7_0);
ACCOUNTS_EXTERN NSString * const ACAccountTypeIdentifierLinkedIn NS_AVAILABLE(NA, NA);
```

**ACAccountTypeIdentifierLinkedIn declared, but NA - not available. May be will work in future.**

Answer (score 0):

you are checking in simulater .. right?

If yes, then go to settings and check in social section linkedin is available or not.